# Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJUnit4' for Android instrumentation test

Tags: android, junit, android-instrumentation

This error has been faced a lot before and asked here. According to the answers, i had to put my instrumentation tests under androidTest folder. So after that, in my case, am still unable to import the **AndroidJunit4** class and the pop-up suggestion dialog has now a new option : **Setup JDK** wich i am surprised with. Anyway i have followed the option and chosen the proper JDK but the problem is still there and the dialog still suggests the same option.

Does anyone know what is the problem here ?

**EDIT : My gradle dependencies:**

```
  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'

androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',   {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
   }
```

Comment: You may not have an `androidTest` dependency to pull in JUnit: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: @CommonsWare, i followed the link you mentionned but it did not help. I have always the same problem. Am gonna edit my post with my gradle dependencies.

Comment: Don't you want "testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' " for junit testing?

Comment: Yes, i do @Christine. What do you mean ?

Comment: Your gradle file says "androidTestCompile". That's different.

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head against the wall and/or any object i see in front of me in order to make my SQLite function unit tested.  No matter what I do, how strictly follow the suggestions provided my many wise people all over the internet did not work.

I then had to go to **preschool and start over to realize my stupid mistake**.  I learned that AndroidJUnit4 can only be used with Instrumentation Test and JUnit must be used for local tests.  That being said, the folder must be **src/androidTest/java**.  I had my test class directly under androidTest folder, hence I had to face that nasty error.  However, the moment I moved it under **src/androidTest/java** everything went very clear like "*I can see clearly now the rain is gone*".

**[Take a look at this article](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)** which says...

> Run Instrumented Unit Tests To run your instrumented tests, follow
>   these steps:
>
> Be sure your project is synchronized with Gradle by clicking Sync
>   Project  in the toolbar. Run your test in one of the following ways:
>   To run a single test, open the Project window, and then right-click a
>   test and click Run . To test all methods in a class, right-click a
>   class or method in the test file and click Run . To run all tests in a
>   directory, right-click on the directory and select Run tests . The
>   Android Plugin for Gradle compiles the instrumented test code located
>   in the default directory (src/androidTest/java/), builds a test APK
>   and production APK, installs both APKs on the connected device or
>   emulator, and runs the tests. Android Studio then displays the results
>   of the instrumented test execution in the Run window.

Therefore folks,  for **instrumentation test the folder must be (do not forget the case)**

> src/androidTest/java

and for **local tests the folder must be**

> src/test/java

You can then have your package folder(s) to match your app package

Hope, this helps for the community!